# $.('.action ') is undefined on Wordpress . $ is not define

Tags: jquery, wordpress

The Jquery is not working with wordpress . its throws $ is undefined .

**Code :**

```
$('.action').on("change",function(e){
// my code
})
```

Comment: try `jQuery('.action')` instead. \

Comment: `$` is just an alias, there are other libraries such as `prototype` which uses the same alias, which causes conflicts with jQuery. If that is not the case, jQuery might not be included, or the jQuery object is assigned to some other variable, using **`noConflict(true)`** method.

Comment: Have you imported jQuery into your code? that is what the $ is. Just add `<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'></script>` in your html before your other JS executes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Wordpress Already Have Inbuild Jquery method so  .

Try This . The Function Change The All `$` to `jquery` and Working Fine .

```
(function($){ // use it as $
   $(document).ready(function(){ // make sure DOM is ready
      $('.action').on("change",function(e){ // bind the change event 
        // my code
      });
   });
})(jQuery); // pass jQuery in the IIFE
```

<strike>No Need To Add Jquery Library</strike>. As wordpress bundles with jQuery internally but uses `jQuery` keyword instead of its alias `$`.

Comment: this answer is fine but incomplete.

Comment: @Jai can you edit this for me

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
 wp_enqueue_script(
        'my_voter_script',
        plugins_url( '/js/main.js' , __FILE__ ),
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
```

On Plugin Init Page  To load External JS file

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress it includes the jquery. Try to replace all `$` with `jQuery` and  check. May be after replace `$` with `jQuery` all working fine.